# Why is the openai API giving multiple requests error even though i just got the api key

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

```
import { config } from "dotenv"
config()

import {Configuration,OpenAIApi    } from "openai"
const openai=new OpenAIApi(new Configuration({
    apiKey:process.env.API_KEY
}))

console.log(process.env.API_KEY);
openai.createChatCompletion({
    model:"text-davinci-002",
    messages:[{role:"user", content:"hi hat"}]
})
.then(res =>{
    console.log(res)
})
```

i have both the .env file aswell as the dependanies installed. But it still gives the error for multiple requests.
Uncaught Error Error: Request failed with status code 429

---

Comment: 429 is the "too many requests"  error.  You're calling the API too often.  You're spamming.

Comment: @JohnGordon i only sent 1 request where it showed an error

Comment: Are you running this code on your local machine, or from a hosted cloud platform?

Comment: if you signed up before and just started to use the api keys, your free usage might expire